# no record inserted in the database in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, insert, save

I have tried many times to insert a product which belongs to a category without change in the database
  **this is controller**

```
class ProduitController extends Controller
{
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $pdt=new Produit(); 
        $pdt->nom=$request->input('nomPdt');
        $pdt->libelle=$request->input('libelle');
        $pdt->qte_stock=$request->input('qte');
        $pdt->pu=$request->input('pu');
        $pdt->categorie_id=$request->input('categorie');
        $pdt->etat=1;

       $pdt->save();
     }}
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{url('produit/'.$pdt->id)}}" method="post">
<label for="nom">nom:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="" name="nom" value=""><br>

<label for="libelle">libellé:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="" name="libelle" value=""><br>

<label for="qte">Qte en stock:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="" name="qte" value="" min="0"><br>

<label for="pu">PU:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="" name="pu" value="" min="0"><br>

<label for="etat">Etat:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="" name="etat" ><br>

<label for="selectCategorie">Categorie:</label>
<select id="" name="selectCategorie">
    <option value="selectionnez">selectionnez</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $cat)
    <option value="{{ $cat->id }}"> {{ $cat->nom }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

for the product table associated with the category table
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which is the error message?

Comment: no error but without insertion

Comment: Your select field has `name="selectCategorie"` in the form, but in the controller you are reading the form value of `categorie` field, which does not exist. You should make them match

Comment: Your form's URL may be incorrect. Try using `action()` or `route()` to point to the route associated with your `ProduitController::store` method.

Answer (score 0):

We aren’t seeing the full picture of the route and uri here. It would be worth verify that. The easiest what to do that would be a temporary `dd(‘here’);` at the top of your controller's store() method to make sure you are reaching the controller method you expect to. Once that’s verified, you can remove the `dd()` and move on with confidence.

A few of the input names you reference within the controller do not match those in your form. You need to make sure everything matches the names from the forms.

```
 $pdt=new Produit(); 
    $pdt->nom=$request->input('nom');
    $pdt->libelle=$request->input('libelle');
    $pdt->qte_stock=$request->input('qte');
    $pdt->pu=$request->input('pu');
    $pdt->categorie_id=$request->input('selectCategorie');
    $pdt->etat=1;//you have this on your form, but have hard coded here?

   $pdt->save();
```

You can also clean this up slightly by loading all the input and using the create() method on the mode.

```
$inputData = $request()->all();

$pdt = Produit::create([
    'nom' => Arr::get($input, 'nom'), 
    'libelle' => Arr::get($input, 'libelle'),
    'qte_stock' => Arr::get($input, 'qte'),
    'pu' => Arr::get($input, 'pu'),
    'categorie_id' => Arr::get($input, 'selectCategorie'),
    'etat’ => 1
]);
```

Hope this gets things working!